# How to reload security principal user info or a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm developing an aspnet mvc application and i have a problem to reload some data, i don't know if the problem is in the security principal info that every view contains or in my partial view that doesn't reload when some other view is shown.

I have a layout page that is used in my whole application, and inside this layout page i have this partial view code fragment:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialActiveClient")
```

this partial view contains the next lines:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("HasClients"))
{
    <p>An Active Client</p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Activate", "Client")">Change active client</a>

}
else
{
    <p>You don't have any clients<p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Client")">Create client</a>
}
```

So when a user creates an account for the first time, this user has 0 clients and doesn't belong to the "HasClients" role and the "you don't have any clients" message is shown, but when this user creates his first client, the user is added to the "HasClients" role by default in my controller. The problem is that the "you don't have any clients" is still there even if i change the views. In order for the other message to show, this user has to log out and then log in again.

So my question is, how can my users see the "An Active Client" message immediately after they create a client?

Comment: Please show the entire (parent) view.  How does the user create a client?  Is it using AJAX forms?

Comment: i'm not using ajax forms, just a regular form in my view and a regular controller. I already solve it, i just wrote the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify my comment to the answer provided by Tchaps. This is the code (not my original code, but make my point) to my solution, like i wrote in the comment, it's not elegant but i works, at least in my case.

```
// Add to role, save changes
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userInSession.Id, roleHaveClients.Name);
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userInSession);
// Sign out / Sing in
_registerManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
await __registerManager.SignInAsync(userInSession, false, false);
// Redirect to another action
return RedirectToAction("someAction","someController");
```

Answer (score 0):

The roles are cached in a cookie , so you can force them to refresh by deleting the cookie. You need to refresh users role. Here is a ways
 you can call this `Roles.DeleteCookie();` and it will clear roles and reload it in the next request.
This is taken from this question page [Refresh ASP.NET Role Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008618/refresh-asp-net-role-provider)

Comment: i tried this solution, but it didn't work. I suppose because i'm using identity 2.0. But i solved it, it is not a elegant solution but it works. In my controller just after i add the user in session  to the "HasClients" role and save changes, i sing out / sing in the user and then redirect him to another action.